# How to add combo box to gridview in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I tried to add combo box in gridview but I get this error:

> Exception: Value of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn' cannot be converted
>   to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField'.

this is my code:

```
Dim bsCountry As BindingSource

            Dim col As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
            col.DataPropertyName = "countryName"
            col.HeaderText = "Country"
            col.Name = "cName"

            col.DataSource = bsCountry
            col.DisplayMember = "countryName"
            col.ValueMember = "countryId"

            GridView2.Columns.Add(col)
            GridView2.DataBind()
```

Comment: A `GridView` is not the same as a `DataGridView`. The fields are also different. The error tells you why.

Comment: I do not understand. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Think you're after what is called a `DropDownList`

Comment: What you're supposed to do is do some research and learn how to use a `GridView`.

Comment: You're supposed to change either the control type or the column type. You're currently using a [**`DataGrid`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) which, as you see in the error, is part of the `System.Web.UI.WebControls` namespace - it is made for web applications. What you should be using if you're using WinForms is the [**`DataGridView`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: can you show me example?